# How to create a login function with Laravel API and VUE client

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, authentication

I am making an application in VUE in which users must log in to access the information.
The login process is done through a Laravel API that will collect the information from a database.

To send the data from the VUE form I do the following in the VUE api:

```
import axios from 'axios';
const baseURL = 'http://batoilogic.my/api/';

export default {
  login(credentials){
    return axios.get(baseURL+'login/'+ credentials)
  }
}
```

And in Laravel I have created a LoginController, with the function that will validate the credentials sent by VUE:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return $credentials;
    } else {
        return $credentials;
    }
}
```

The problem is that no data is being passed from VUE to Laravel. I don't know where I have the problem. It may not be the correct way to send the information.
I need help.

Comment: For a login, I think you should perform a POST request, sending the credentials as json or formdata

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.post(baseURL+'login/', {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```